# how footerdata set jqgrid set dynmaic column

Tags: jqgrid, mvcgrid

iam create jqgrid dynmamic but i have problem. when create footer  jqgrid

> call function sumarValores() for footer in loadComplete
>   but dont know global when use **$self.jqGrid** 
>   Must use Price_Num instead of global ;but I do not want use Price_Num direct in **$self.jqGrid** 
>   iam want create dynmamic footer.
>
> ```
> dataArray = [
>       { id_R: 1, Name_c: "dummy1",  AddDate_D: "1394/07/27", Price_Num: "10000" },
>       { id_R: 2, Name_c: "dummy2", AddDate_D: "1394/07/28", Price_Num: "120000" },
> ```

];
this my code

```
 $('#list').jqGrid({
        caption: "",    
        datatype: 'local',
        colNames: getColNames(dataArray[0]),
        colModel: getColModels(dataArray[0]),
     footerrow : true,
    loadComplete: function () {
            sumarValores($(this))
          },
});
function sumarValores($self) {
    var sumaHa = 0;
    var columnNames = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames');
    var global;
    for (var z = 0; z < columnNames.length; z++) {
        var colN = columnNames[z];
        if (colN == "Price")
        {
            colN = colN.concat('_Num');
            global =  colN;
            var sumCanceled = $self.jqGrid("getCol", colN, false, "sum");
            break;
        }

    }

    alert(colN);
    global ='Price_Num';
    $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
        global : sumCanceled,

    });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see here is that you can't set the object property the way you do.

```
global ='Price_Num';
$self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
    global : sumCanceled,

});
```

To overcome this you can do

```
global ='Price_Num';
var footer = {};
footer[global] = sumCanceled;
$self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", footer );
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To be able to write in the footer you need to have the footer row. Please verify that you use `footerrow: true` option in jqGrid.

Comment: iam use   footerrow : true,

Comment: @saeed3164: You should post the code, which you use. The original code don't have `footerrow : true`!!! In the same way it's unclear other options, which you use. For example, do you use `data` option? How and when you fill the data, which you want to sum and place in the footer? The next question: you set `global` property by `footerData` method. Do you have visible column in `colModel` with the name? You don't posted it too. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid? It's better if you prepare the demo in jsfiddle, for example, which demonstrate the problem.